# Calculate the second-order derivative.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be our variable. I would like to know what is:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \text{Tr}\big((A+B^\text{T}\textbf{diag}(x)B)^{-1}\big)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}.
$$
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $ and $(A+B^\text{T}\textbf{diag}(x)B)$ is invertible.

The $\textbf{diag}$ operator on a matrix results in a vector of diagonal elements and $\textbf{diag}$ on a vector results in a matrix with diagonal elements on the main diagonal and zero elsewhere.

Hint: via matrixcookbook, I figured out that:
$$
\frac{\partial \text{Tr}\big((A+B^\text{T}\textbf{diag}(x)B)^{-1}\big)}{\partial x} = \textbf{diag}(B(A+B^\text{T}\textbf{diag}(x)B)^{-2}B^{\text{T}})
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 X &= {\rm Diag}(x) \cr
 U &= A + B^TXB \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these variables and find its gradient
$$\eqalign{
  f &= {\rm tr}(U^{-1}) \cr\cr
 df &= -U^{-2}:dU \cr
   &= -U^{-2}:(B^TdXB) \cr
   &= -BU^{-2}B^T:dX \cr
   &= -BU^{-2}B^T:{\rm Diag}(dx) \cr
   &= -{\rm diag}(BU^{-2}B^T)^T\,dx \cr\cr
 g &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -{\rm diag}(BU^{-2}B^T) \cr
}$$
which confirms the result from the Cookbook.

Next, find the gradient of $g$
$$\eqalign{
 dg &= {\rm diag}\Big(B\big\{U^{-2}(dU)U^{-1}+U^{-1}(dU)U^{-2}\big\}B^T\Big) \cr
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(BU^{-2}(B^TdXB)U^{-1}B^T\Big) + {\rm diag}\Big(BU^{-1}(B^TdXB)U^{-2}B^T\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
Now we need this Hadamard product trick
$${\rm diag}(AXB) = (B^T\circ A)\,x$$
to eliminate the diag() operators
$$\eqalign{
 dg &= \Big[(BU^{-1}B^T)^T\circ(BU^{-2}B^T) +  (BU^{-2}B^T)^T\circ(BU^{-1}B^T)\Big]\,dx \cr\cr
 H &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = (BU^{-T}B^T)\circ(BU^{-2}B^T) + (BU^{-2T}B^T)\circ(BU^{-1}B^T) \cr\cr
}$$
This result is the Hessian of the function which you asked about.

A nice way to summarize these results is
$$\eqalign{
 F &= BU^{-1}B^T \cr
 G &= BU^{-2}B^T \cr
 H &= F^T\circ G + G^T\circ F\cr
 g &= -{\rm diag}(G) \cr
}$$

Comment: Updated the answer to correct the sign of the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l:x\rightarrow U=A+B^Tdiag(x)B, f=U\rightarrow tr(U^{-1}),g=f\circ l:x\rightarrow f(U)$ and $L_i$ be the $i^{th}$ row of $B$.

Since $l$ is an affine function, $Dl:h\in \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow B^Tdiag(h)B$ and $D^2g_x(h,k)=D^2f_U(Dl(h),Dl(k))$. Moreover$Dl(e_i)=L_i^TL_i$ where $(e_i)_i$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Note that $\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)=D^2g_x(e_i,e_j)=D^2f_U(Dl(e_i),Dl(e_j))=D^2f_U(H,K)$ where $H=L_i^TL_i,K=L_j^TL_j\in M_{n}$.

Here $Df_U(H)=-tr(U^{-1}HU^{-1})=-tr(U^{-2}H)$ and $D^2f_U(H,K)=tr(U^{-2}KU^{-1}H+U^{-1}KU^{-2}H)$.

Conclusion. $\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)=D^2g_x(e_i,e_j)=tr(U^{-2}L_j^TL_jU^{-1}L_i^TL_i+U^{-1}L_j^TL_jU^{-2}L_i^TL_i)$.

Comment: lynn just answered thank you anyway.